# How do I access System.Web.Http.Current.Response from a within a thread?

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET page with a WebMethod that creates an object and runs one of the object's methods in a new thread.

I need to access the `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType` property from within this thread.

Each time I (try to) access it, I receive a `NullReferenceException`.

Is this posible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `HttpContext.Current` returns the instance for the current thread. Since you are executing in another thread, you can't access it this way. Try to pass the `ContentType` to your thread, but be careful in passing a `HttpResponse` object to another thread, since it is not thread-safe.